# Crear una condición de llenado

Tags: python, condiciones

Como están , Estoy haciendo un programa que va documentando informacion de unos textbox y los presenta en un excel.

Intento hacer una condicion para que si un textbox no es contestado, deje su tupla en blanco y baje al siguiente.

```
if TxtBox1:
    rows[0].append(TxtBox1)

if TxtBox2:
    rows[1].append(TxtBox2)

if TxtBox3:
    rows[2].append(TxtBox3)
```

Rows[].append me sirve para acomodar el valor obtenido en el txtbox.

He intentado varias formas pero hasta ahora sin exito. como puede funcionar? gracias a todos

Comment: ¿Qué contiene TxtBox1 cuando no es llenado? ¿Es `None` o algun otro valor? ¿Qué es "en blanco" ... un string vacio, una lista vacía ... ?

Comment: El txtbox en mi programa es llenado unicamente con numeros, 
En blanco me refiero a que en el documento se vea su celda vacia. 
Si el textbox1 no es llenado, en el excel su casilla quede vacia. Porque con el codigo que tengo si no es llenado el textbox1 lo remplaza el siguiente que si es contestado

Comment: `if TxtBox1: rows[0].append(TxtBox1) else: rows[0].append("")`

Comment: Gracias Candid es eso!